# On a planet with a large amount of water vapor (steam) would senses evolve

Tags: science-fiction, xenobiology, aliens, fauna, senses

So imagine a planet with large amounts of subsurface liquid water. Geysers appear in big groups, and pools of warm water are common. So the planet is now covered in water vapor (steam) in the forms of surface clouds that provide visibility of about 3 feet away. The planet is warmer than earth so during warmer days water evaporates causing a odd foggy drought. How would mobile life evolve senses. I came up with trunked creatures that have amazing sense of smell and large wing spanned kite like predators.

Comment: Hi Vega, and welcome to the site.  As it stands, this question needs some refinement before it can be meaningfully answered.  Surface clouds do not necessarily equate with zero visibility (and sufficient suspended water vapour would be extremely difficult to maintain).  Are you saying that visibility is zero/near zero?   What are the constraints?

Comment: Hi jdunlop I am happy to be here and I added some detail that may help.

Comment: Water vapor is relatively transparent to certain light wavelengths outside of the visible spectrum.  Maybe creatures will evolve to see in those frequencies?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water and also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_band#/media/File:Atmospheric_Transmission.png

Comment: so the creatures may see like bees looking at the absorption band takes in no uv light

Comment: Doe this much water vapor change sound frequencies? I know sound seems to travel differently in really dry air (like winter). Does it affect the propagation of odor in the air? The droplets might absorb a lot of the compounds that transmit smells, but it's outside my area.

Comment: I'm pretty sure water is known for absorbing odors so thats why I had the idea of mostly smell based life forms and sound is muffled in fog so sound is not very useful really if the creatures did evolve ears they wouldn't be very useful unless they could be moved to help pinpoint sounds

Answer (score 1):

Eyes are still very viable. Even short ranged due to all the vapor it gives a great advantage in evading or attacking other creatures. Especially as you want to know quickly where someone is and how they move towards you. Light is simply the best form of getting quick information. Sound and smell are relatively slow and can be more easily be ysed against you, while light is harder to generate or trick. Eyes would be kore rudimentary and largely focus on seeing shapes, leaving out colour and further detail. "Visible" light in the real world is used because it has a high energy, making it easier to see as you don't need to evolve insanely sensitive eyes. That being said, after long enough some rare few might get sensitive enough to see other frequencies. As @cowlinator says, all the water vapor might seem transparant in some other wavelength.

Sound would be the second, if the geisers aren't too loud. My feeling however says it would be rudimentary as well, looking at deep sea creatures near volcanism. Although not accurate, I think it would have a great many similarities. Sound moves strangely with a lot of water vapor. Eyes are not incredibly useful.
A nose could actually be useful if it can immediately seperate excess water, which isn't too hard I think. It can give direction (like snakes) and tell a lot from the environment. Supplemented by rudimentary hearing and sight, your trunk people might work.

But lastly we should check vibrations. Much like hearing, but might help navigation with feeling air or ground vibrations. Think some creatures able to feel vibrations in the air from wingbeats elephants communicating by stomping on the ground.

But I find I'm heavily speculating. Maybe someone else has a more grounded explanation.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. vibrations would be useful i would think maybe rattling stiff appendages like a rattle snake could be affective communication. by making them louder and quieter and duration an maybe bioluminscents could be used for communication and warning like marsallars waving horns around